# Silverlight wcf lag when calling functions

Tags: wcf, performance, silverlight-3.0

I am trying to debug performance issues with a .net 3.5 silverlight 3 - wcf service based application. the service is running under IIS 7 on a server that is not under heavy load

The problem is that certain actions in the application are taking a long time to complete, in an attempt to debug this we have added manual loggin into the silverlight and wcf application to time how long calls from the silverlight client take to reach the service, how long for the service to process, then how long for the response to reach the client

Are findings show that we seem to be getting large delays - up to 45 seconds between messages being sent and received to and from the server.

Unfortunately these large delays seem to be happening randomly, to different service calls we no pattern. The majority of the time calls work relatively quickl.

I believe this may be related to concurrent usage, as the issue appears to get worse when 4- 5 users are using the system at once.

Has anyone else experienced issues like this? And could anyone advise any usefull ways to debug this kind of issue or at least narrow down the possible causes?

When running in debug or via IIS locally on a development machine this issue does not occur

Thanks!